# Refresh page in Dynamics crm after flow run

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, power-automate

I want to know if there is any idea to refresh Dynamics crm page after running a Power Automate (Flow). 
The flow updated fields in the quote entity and I want to refresh the page after the Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your flow been Trigerred? As Arun said there are 2 different systems been used here.
But let me try another Idea.

How about you add javascript and through [Javascript trigger your flow](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2019/10/how-to-run-microsoft-flow-through-custom-ribbon-button-using-http-request/), you can have http request to trigger a flow and it is not a big deal.

Now add a [promise](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-promises/) in your Js which will wait for response from Flow and once you get the response you can refresh the Dynamics Page.

Comment: the flow run using a workbench buton and javascript  Http request. can you clarify more how can i do the response from the flow to the javascript. Thank u so much.

Comment: if you follow the  [Javascript Trigger your flow](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2019/10/how-to-run-microsoft-flow-through-custom-ribbon-button-using-http-request/)  example, Javascript itself calls Flow and use promise and check if status is 200 or 204 or 202. In example it tries to open dialog rather in your case just try to refresh a page. [Docs Links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-data/refresh)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may not be a feasible thing, as these are two different platforms integrated to do some powerful background handshakes. Flow got triggered  and actioned to sync back the data in CRM is integration scenario and totally client side UI agnostic - so form refresh is needed in timely fashion or manual user refresh to see latest data.

You may submit an idea [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/idb-p/MPAIdeas) for community support.